# Put the header inside a box

Tags: header-footer, box

I want to put the whole header of the document inside a box similar to the one created by the `\fbox`.
I don't want the box to include the main body or the footer.
How can I do that?

At this moment I have achieved this as as following:

```
\fancyhead[L]{
    \fbox{%
        \parbox{0.97\textwidth}{%
            \raisebox{-0.4\height}{%
                \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{logo.png}
            }
        }
    }
}
\fancyhead[C]{Document title}
\fancyhead[R]{}
```

but there are issues with the box not being able to span the whole width of the page without overflowing.

Comment: Did you try achieving this using `fancyhdr`? Sounds the perfect job for that package as you can design a custom header.

Comment: @alchemist I have achieved it (I will add my code in the question) but it seems like a hack. Also I can't get the box to span the whole width of the page without overflowing.

Comment: I wait to see your code then. Maybe I can help you out with that overflowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tinkered a bit around using your code as a starting point. I obtained this answer, which seems to satisfy your requirements.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{boxedwh}{
    \setlength{\headheight}{36pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{9pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{
        \fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                \raisebox{-0.4\height}{%
                    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=15mm]{logo.png}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    \fancyhead[C]{\raisebox{30pt}{Document title}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{30pt}{\thepage}}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{boxedwh}
    
    \lipsum[3][1-3]
        
\end{document}
```

I altered the following points:

1. Part of the *overflowing* was due to the head rule of `fancyhdr` itself, so I reset that to zero width.
2. The header style needs to be named, so I choose `boxedwh`.
3. Using logo's inside a header means altering the space available to the header. So I included a random value as `height` inside the `\includegraphics`, set the head height to 36pt (which seems to be large enough) and added some space to the `top margin` to lower the header.
4. Gave the `\parbox` the full text length.
5. As that pushes the central and right header to the next line, I used `\raisebox` to put them back in the boxed header.

This results in this header:

[image: boxed header]

There is still a slight overflow next to the page number. Changing the width of the `parbox` to `0.98\textwidth` aligns the header with the right margin, but then the page number is directly at the right border of the `'fbox`. So the page number has to be printed in the footer, leaving the right header empty. Optically the header box then aligns with the right margin.

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected!